# for loop not working in some devices

Tags: android

i have written this code which displays the available wifi accesspoints and their signal strength continously....
for loop in the code to append the scan results in stringBuffer is working on some android phones properly but on some phones like nexus 5 it skips the "for loop" code part.... if anybody can help me with that i ll be very greatful. 
Thanks in Advance

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Switch aswitch;
    int n=1;
    TextView text;
    WifiManager wifi;
    String message;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        aswitch=(Switch)findViewById(R.id.myswitch);
        wifi=(WifiManager)getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytv);

        aswitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // do something, the isChecked will be
                // true if the switch is in the On position
                if (isChecked && !wifi.isWifiEnabled()) {
                    wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
                    message="enabled";
                    text.setText(message);


                } else if (!isChecked && wifi.isWifiEnabled()){
                    wifi.setWifiEnabled(false);
                    message="disabled";
                    text.setText(message);
                }
            }
        });

            MyBroadcastReceiver broadcast=new MyBroadcastReceiver();
            registerReceiver(broadcast, new IntentFilter(wifi.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));



    }
    class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            StringBuffer stringBuffer=new StringBuffer();
            List<ScanResult> list=wifi.getScanResults();

            for(ScanResult scanResult:list){
                String ssid0 = scanResult.SSID;
                int rssi0 = scanResult.level;
                String rssiString0 = String.valueOf(rssi0);
                stringBuffer.append("\n SSID:" + ssid0 + "   RSSI:" + rssiString0 +"dBm");
                text.setText("yes");
            }
            text.setText(stringBuffer);
            if(wifi.isWifiEnabled()){
                wifi.startScan();
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt it's actually just skipping the for loop. Have you ensured `list` actually contains elements?

Comment: yes i have checked it....the same code works perfectly on the samsung

Comment: Is the input on different devices the same as on the Samsung? I agree with Carcigenicate, if somethign is wrong it is most likely the input. Possibly WiFi is off

Comment: it is absolutely the same,same code... i have tested it again and again on both devices but God knows whats wrong with it.

Comment: i see the problem...list is always empty in case of nexus phones that s why for loop isn't working...But i cant understand why the list is empty??